# Find the normalized eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T=\begin{pmatrix}5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & i\\ 0 & -i & 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

I found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors already and they are $1,3,5$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\-i\\1\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix}0\\i\\1\end{pmatrix}$, and $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

According to mathematica, their orthoganalized form will be $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 0 & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

But I am getting wildly different answers when I try to find the normalized eigenvectors using the Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: Well, from you eigenvectors, it is clear what the orthogonal ones are. Are you using GS because you have to and are trying to validate that result?

Comment: You shouldn't be using GS at all. Just normalize each eigenvector individually. And keep in mind that even normalized eigenvectors are not unique---you can multiply them by any unit-magnitude complex scalar.

Comment: You happen to have orthogonal eigenvectors. But if you hadn't, then making them orthonormal would most likely spoil the property of being eigenvectors (for instance it would be _sure_ to spoil that property given that there are no repeated eigenvalues).

Answer (score 1):

You may be right. There is no unique orthonormal basis. Just check that whatever you are getting are eigenvectors, are orthogonal and have norm $1$ each.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix that Mathematica gives is *not* the matrix formed by the unit eigenvectors, but the conjugate transpose of it. That is, it is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $T = U^\ast\pmatrix{5\\ &1\\ &&3}U$. You can easily see that the columns of $U^\ast$ are scalar multiples of your three eigenvectors.