# Positive definite matrix and unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Problem: Find the conditions for $a$ such that matrix $A$ is positive definite.

$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & a \\
a & 1 & a \\
a & a & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Also, find the unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^{-1}AU$ is a diagonal matrix.

Attempt: I'm struggling to understand the definition and characteristics of positive definite. Can someone point me towards the solution?

Comment: You could try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) or one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations)

Answer (score 1):

one  understanding of positive definitive is  to have all eigenvalue  positive,or  whole determinant and   also minor determinants should be  greater then $0$,for example let us consider

$(1-a^2)>0$

which means that  from  negative infinity to $-1$ or   from   $1$ to infinity,also

$(a^2-a)>0$

or

$a(a-1)>0$

or from negative infinity to $0$ or  $1$ to infinity

as determinant    we have

```
syms a;
>> A=[1 a a;a 1 a;a a 1]

A =

[ 1, a, a]
[ a, 1, a]
[ a, a, 1]

>> det(A)

ans =

2*a^3 - 3*a^2 + 1
```

ans must be positive,or

```
[V D]=eig(A)

V =

[ -1, -1, 1]
[  1,  0, 1]
[  0,  1, 1]


D =

[ 1 - a,     0,       0]
[     0, 1 - a,       0]
[     0,     0, 2*a + 1]
```

we have

$(1-a)>0$  means that $1>a$

$2*a+1>0$

means that $a>-0.5$ ,so we have

$1>a$  and $a>-0.5$

about unitary  matrix

[Finding a unitary matrix that diagonalizes a given matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405932/finding-a-unitary-matrix-that-diagonalizes-a-given-matrix)

Comment: If $1-a>0$ then $1>a$ not $a>1$.

Comment: yes sorry i will update ,just typo